# jquery: hide a sibling element in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my table in HTML.

```
<table id="all-tasks-display-table">
<thead>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><input id="j_id0:acc-details:all-tasks-list-repeat:0:all-tasks-is-completed" type="checkbox" name="j_id0:acc-details:all-tasks-list-repeat:0:all-tasks-is-completed" checked="checked">
    <td><span id="j_id0:acc-details:all-tasks-list-repeat:0:all-tasks-name">ALPHA</span></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input id="j_id1:acc-details:all-tasks-list-repeat:0:all-tasks-is-completed" type="checkbox" name="j_id1:acc-details:all-tasks-list-repeat:1:all-tasks-is-completed">
    <td><span id="j_id1:acc-details:all-tasks-list-repeat:0:all-tasks-name">BETA</span></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to know how to use jquery to hide the second column (id ending with "...tasks-name") if the first column (checkbox) (id ending with "....tasks-is-completed") is "checked"

Is this possible to do in jquery ?

If it is not a table then I can do something like

```
$("[id$='all-tasks-is-completed']").hide();
```

But since it is occuring within a table I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: So hide the row

Answer (score 0):

So use :has() with the tr to select the rows.

```
$("tr:has([id$='all-tasks-is-completed'])").hide();
```

The other way you can do it is with closest

```
$("[id$='all-tasks-is-completed']").closest("tr").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming the html mark up is the same all the time use `closest()` to get the parent tr then use `find()` to find the target span then use `parent()` to target the column parent td then use `hide()` to hide

```js
$("[id$='all-tasks-is-completed']").change(function() {

  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find("span[id$='all-tasks-name']").hide();
  }

}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="all-tasks-display-table">
  <thead>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="j_id0:acc-details:all-tasks-list-repeat:0:all-tasks-is-completed" type="checkbox" name="j_id0:acc-details:all-tasks-list-repeat:0:all-tasks-is-completed" checked="checked" /></td>
      <td><a><span id="j_id0:acc-details:all-tasks-list-repeat:0:all-tasks-name">ALPHA</span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="j_id1:acc-details:all-tasks-list-repeat:0:all-tasks-is-completed" type="checkbox" name="j_id1:acc-details:all-tasks-list-repeat:1:all-tasks-is-completed">
        <td><a><span id="j_id1:acc-details:all-tasks-list-repeat:0:all-tasks-name">BETA</span></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```